# Silverlight 4: Upload file control?

Tags: silverlight, file-upload

I'm looking for a simple control that will allow the user to upload an image (or any file, really.) However, I'm not seeing it in the VS 2010 control toolbox. Is there something I'm overlooking? What's the idiomatic way to do file upload?

I am developing a Silverlight app hosted in a ASP.NET page from Windows Azure.

Thanks. I'm new to Silverlight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most widely used file upload control suggested by Tim Huer is [the  sl file uploader](http://slfileupload.codeplex.com/). It allows you uploading through wcf or asp.net handler. It supports multiple files, a lite version for single file uploads.

Comment: Cool. How do I actually go about adding that to my app and making it accessible from VS?

Comment: They will give you a dll. You then add it as a reference to your project or you can select add tool in the vs toolbox and browse to the dll. This is not so much of a drag and drop though, as you will need to do some hand coding.

Comment: Ok, and what if I want to make my own control at some point in the future?

Comment: Almost everything you make in silverlight is a control. They are mainly called usercontrols. You can also make and compile actual controls that can be extended, etc.

Comment: There was actually no .dll in the download from that site - just a VS project. How can I go from source code to a usable control?

Comment: dont download the source, download the binary. That contains the dll. If anything, build the source, then look in the bin folder for the dll.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a control that should help you in your effort: [Parallel upload to Azure via Silverlight Control](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlight/Silverlight-Azure-Blob-3b773e26)